# Fitting a model in R, Least squares estimates

Tags: statistics, math-software

$ \Bbb E$(grades) =
$\bigg(\alpha$, teacher='Female',

and,

$\bigg( \alpha+\beta $, teacher='Male'

given that I have loaded up the required data, how should I go about fitting this model in R? Then I need to find the least squared estimates of both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which I think I will be able to do once I can fit the model.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For discrete variables like Male vs. Female, the best you can do is average the population.  So $\alpha=$ average grade from a Female teacher, $\beta=$average grade from a Male teacher minus $\alpha$

Comment: so now I understand how the variables can make sense, but I don't know how I would use R to average grades from male and female separately.

Comment: @cheeseman123:  I don't know R at all, so can't help there.